# Find the $n^{th}$ term and the sum to $n$ terms of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic-progressions

Find the $n^{th}$ term and sum to $n$ terms of the following series.
$$1.3+2.4+3.5+……$$

My Attempt:

Here, 
$n^{th}$ term of $1+2+3+……=n$

$n^{th}$ term of $3+4+5+……=n+2$

Thus,

$n^{th}$ term of the series $1.3+2.4+3.5+……=n(n+2)$

$$t_n=n^2+2n$$

If $S_n$ be the sum to $n$ terms of the series then
$$S_n=\sum t_n$$
$$=\sum (n^2+2n)$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: Is that multiplication or decimals? Also did you mean $n(n+2)$?

Comment: Use \cdot  e.g $1\cdot 3$ for multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n (i^2+2i) &=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^n i\\
&= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}  \end{align}

You might want to factorize the terms to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

With the summation:

$$\sum n^2+2n$$

Split it into two via linearity:

$$\sum n^2 + 2\sum n$$

Then apply for the formulae for the sum of first $n$ numbers and $n$ squares:

$$\sum n^2 = {n(n+1)(2n+1)\over 6}$$
$$\sum n = {n(n+1)\over 2}$$

Thus producing:

$${n(n+1)(2n+1)\over 6} + n(n+1)$$